# \tcbox inside of tabu sticks out

Tags: tabu, tcolorbox, height

I use `\tcbox` inside of `tabu` environment cells.
As you see at the screenshot, the tabu is enclosed in `tcolorbox` as well.

So, `tabu` doesn't measure the size of the content in the cells, when the content is a `\tcbox`-ed, making the row of one-line height.

How to fix this? How to tell `tabu` to expand the row, without manual setting of the row height?

The source code below has another chinese and cyrillic characters than in the screenshot, but the structure is the same.

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Металл, colback=badcolor, colbacktitle=jincolor]
    \begin{tabu}{X[-1c]|X[-1c]|X[-1c]X[l]}
        \tabucline-
        \multirow{1}{*}{\tcbox{6}} &
        \multirow{1}{*}{\tcbox{⬆︎戊} } &
        Мистик в могиле &

        \tabularnewline
        \tabucline-
    \end{tabu}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please provide a simple, complete document illustrating the problem mentioned?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. As Gonzalo Medina says, please show us the code to reproduce the problem. It is harder to help when all you have is the picture.